# Can you prove the simplification of this sum?

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm still learning Calculus (in parallel) and I'm stuck on this sum simplification. It is the 2nd part of the Tail to expectation formula from statistics #1.

From here :
$$
\sum_{k=a+1}^{b} \frac{ b-k+1} {b-a+1 }
$$
I need to get there: 
$$
\frac{ b-a } { 2 }
$$

Any idea on the needed algebraic operations to perform this simplification?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks everyone,

I could solve it. 

Was good practice, 

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1342633
$\sum_{k=a+1}^b\left[\frac{b-k+1}{b-a+1}\right]\to\frac{\sum_{k=a+1}^b\left[{b-k+1}\right]}{b-a+1}\to$
$\frac{\sum_{k=a+1}^b\left[b\right]-\sum_{k=a+1}^b\left[k\right]+\sum_{k=a+1}^b\left[1\right]}{b-a+1}\to$
$\frac{b(b-a)
-({\frac{b^2+b}2}-{\frac{a^2+a}2})
+b-a}{b-a+1}\to$
$\frac{2b(b-a)
-b^2-b+a^2+a
+2b-2a}{2b-2a+2}$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

I’ll get you started:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=a+1}^b\frac{b-k+1}{b-a+1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{b-a}\frac{b-(a+k)+1}{b-a+1}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{b-a}\left(1-\frac{k}{b-a+1}\right)\\\\
&=b-a-\frac1{b-a+1}\sum_{k=1}^{b-a}k
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=a+1}^{b} \frac{b-k+1}{b-a+1} & = \sum_{k=a+1}^{b} \frac{b+1}{b-a+1} -\sum_{k=a+1}^{b} \frac{k}{b-a+1}\\
 & =  (b-a)\frac{b+1}{b-a+1}-\frac{1}{b-a+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^b k-\sum_{k=1}^a k\right)\\ 
 & = (b-a)\frac{b+1}{b-a+1}-\frac{1}{b-a+1}\left[\frac{b(b+1)}{2}-\frac{a(a+1)}{2}\right] \\
\end{align}$$

You should be able to continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the sum without $\Sigma$ :$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=a+1}^{b}\frac{b-k+1}{b-a+1}&=\frac{1}{b-a+1}\sum_{k=a+1}^{b}(b-k+1)\\&=\frac{1}{b-a+1}\left((b-(a+1)+1)+(b-(a+2)+1)+\cdots+2+1\right)\\&=\frac{1}{b-a+1}\left(1+2+\cdots+(b-a-1)+(b-a)\right)\\&=\frac{1}{b-a+1}\cdot\frac{(b-a)(b-a+1)}{2}\end{align}$$